# How to know what specific notification was launched

Tags: ios, xamarin, notifications, xamarin.ios

I can have a few notifications in my app and want to do different action depending on notification. I can detect if the app was launched from notification from launchOptions in FinishedLaunching method, also I can handle it in some methods in AppDelegate. But how to know what specific notification was launched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method:

```
public virtual Boolean FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
```

the [launchOptions](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplicationDelegate.FinishedLaunching/p/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary/) dictionary will tell your which notification was received

Comment: Thanks, I thought launchOptions show only if the app was launched from notification but not notification properties!